# Can a home rest permanently on two steel beams?

Tags: foundation

My home has settling due to sitting on clay soils.

I've seen homes that get new foundations rebuilt sitting in one or two large steel beams and wondered, if those are themselves underpinned to bedrock, can a home safely sit on these indefinitely? Mostly I'm curious but also wonder if that would result in less underpinning and a more even floor throughout the home.

Comment: Could work - talk to an engineer about it, you'll certanly need one if you do it. Note that houses sitting on a few beams are not, in general, OCCUPIED while sitting on said beams. And the beams themselves are not cheap (in normal use you are effectively renting them from the housemoving company as part of their service.)

Comment: A beam can be used to support a wall in place of a lot of individual piers provided the beam is properly supported.  That would be a cost tradeoff.  The wall would need to be temporarily jacked up in all the places piers would go in order to install the beam, and the beam would likely rest on a couple of piers.  The beam also needs to be incorporated into the existing foundation, so the total job wouldn't necessarily be cheaper.  On a house designed to sit on a regular foundation, you would still need to support every wall, you couldn't just stick a beam under two sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the house could sit on beams if attached to the beams properly. I live in a high seismic area and we build homes 6-10 feet above ground due to flooding from possible seismic activity. The homes are set on beams which are set on posts (piles or caissons). Yours wouldn't need to be that high of course, so contact a STRUCTURAL engineer not a CIVIL engineer to see if it's possible in your area.

Also, there are other types of repairs like "ram jacks" that you could google and locate a company to give you a quote. I think the cost is about $150 to $300 per pier, depending on size, depth required, etc.

Comment: Isn't the construction you describe designed for that purpose from the start?  A house built on a normal foundation isn't likely to be designed to be supported on just two sides.  It is likely to need a supporting framework under the entire perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Those steel beams will still rest on the clay which is still shifting but they are used to reinforce the house and allow it to move off to the side for a bit while the machines go and drive in the piles and pour the new foundation.

On note of the piles, they may not actually reach down to bedrock but instead go down and hold a chunk of clay. This means that more ground needs to move before the house itself will move.